# What programming language that I shall use If I want to develop a new "registration and login" method?

Tags: php, mysql, security, authentication, registration

If I want to develop a new "registration and login" method with a different logic, using mathematics equations and simple algorithms to enhance the current level of security in registration and loging-in step, what programming language that I shall use? 
I seek the simplicity in coding and high speed abilities in processing the script.

I found that I may use PHP..! Is it a correct choice? Or there's an easiest programming language that will help me in this matter?

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Do you want it online? What are the requirements?

Comment: The best thing about security is : not do it yourself. Use proven methods from the people that actually know what they are doing. If you you are at the level of not knowing what you can use, maybe using php... you might be not the one to implement it.

Comment: @Robuust: I need to use it online, and I want to offer it as an alternative login method that you can implement it in your website like OpenID to reduce customer care and password recovery costs! or even consider it as another online tool to login your membership safely.

Comment: @Nanne: Of course i'm not going to implement such a high level of security issue.. but all what I need is to develop a simple trick to reduce login problems.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a web interface, it is probably the right solution it your complexity is not too high. For very high complexity (long running time), use perhaps C, invoked by PHP.

If you use some (desktop-)game, then there exist better solutions like really compiled languages.

And best, use some predefined algorithms, where you know that they're secure. Your own algorithm may have security problems you couldn't imagine yourself.